# Code Coverage Increase

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

What I am missing I can not do the code coverage for the for loop.

```
public class myControllerClass{

public string aText{get;set;}

public string iText{get;set;}

    public myControllerClass () 
    {
        String userId;
        List<User> uList; 
        try
        {   

                userId=Userinfo.getUserId();


                if(userId!=null && userId!='')
                {
                    uList=[SELECT id,Business_Unit__c,Country__c, Language__c,LanguageLocaleKey,IsActive FROM User WHERE ID=:userId AND IsActive=True LIMIT 1];

                    if(uList[0].LanguageLocaleKey == 'en_US') {
                       uList[0].Language__c ='English';
                    }
                    System.Debug('Current User List' + uList);
                }
        }
        Catch(System.NullPointerException e)
        {

        }   


        List<Message__c> msgList =[SELECT
            SP.Name,
            SP.Region__c,
            SP.Country__c,
            SP.Language__c,
            SP.Description__c,
            SP.Context__c,
            SP.Key__c,
            SP.Active__c
            FROM Message__cSP
            WHERE SP.Region__c =: UList[0].Business_Unit__c
            AND SP.Country__c=:UList[0].Country__c
            AND SP.Language__c=:UList[0].Language__c
            AND SP.Context__c = 'Contracts'
            AND ((SP.Key__c = 'Asset_Register') OR (SP.Key__c = 'Invoice_Status') )
            AND SP.Active__c=:TRUE
            ];
         System.Debug('msgList:' + msgList);


         for(Message__citem : msgList){
           if(item.Key__c == 'Asset_Register) {
             assetDisplayText = item.Description__c;
           } else if(item.Key__c == 'Invoice_Status’) {
             invoiceDisplayText = item.Description__c;
           }
         }

    }   
    }
}
```

***************Test Class************

```
 @isTest
    public class ContractsHoverOverTest{

        private static User createUser(String region){
            String nameStr = ''+Datetime.now().getTime();
            String alias = (''+Datetime.now().getTime()).substring(8);

            Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 

            User u = new User(Alias = alias, Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName=nameStr, LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName=nameStr+'@testorg.com', 
            Business_Unit__c=region);
            return u;
        }

        private static List<CP_Messages__c> createMessage(){
            List<CP_Messages__c> msgList = new List<CP_Messages__c>();

            CP_Messages__c msgEng = new CP_Messages__c();

            msgEng.Region__c ='EM';
            msgEng.Country__c = 'United Kingdom';
            msgEng.Language__c = 'English';
            msgEng.Context__c = 'Contracts';
            msgEng.Key__c ='Invoice_Status_hoverover';
            msgEng.Active__c = true;
            msgEng.Description__c = 'This is United Kingdom Language';

            msgList.add(msgEng);

            CP_Messages__c msgGer = new CP_Messages__c();

            msgGer.Region__c ='EMEA';
            msgGer.Country__c = 'Germany';
            msgGer.Language__c = 'German';
            msgGer.Context__c = 'Contracts';
            msgGer.Key__c ='Asset_Register_hoverover';
            msgGer.Active__c = true;
            msgGer.Description__c = 'This is German Langaiage';

            msgList.add(msgGer);

            return msgList;        
        }   
        static testMethod void contractPageHoverOver(){

           User usr =  createUser('United Kingdom');
           insert usr;
           System.assertEquals(usr.LanguageLocaleKey, 'en_US');

           System.runAs(usr){
               List<CP_Messages__c> msg = createMessage();
               insert msg;

                System.assertEquals(msg.size(),2);

                PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/ContractsList');
                Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);
               // ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put(msg);
                myControllerClass ctrl = new myControllerClass ();

           }       
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

You need to set the message **context__c** in your test to equal **Contracts**
because of this line in your class

```
AND SP.Context__c = 'Contracts
```

In addition make sure your user values are equal to what is expected

```
WHERE SP.Region__c =: UList[0].Business_Unit__c
        AND SP.Country__c=:UList[0].Country__c
        AND SP.Language__c=:UList[0].Language__c
```

Check that the user you are creating has the values

Business_unit__c = EMEA

Country__c = United Kingdom OR Germany

Language__c = English or German

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refactor your controller to be easier to test. The loop can be its own method. The method name can serve as a comment. Ie

```
private void setAssetAndInvoiceDisplayText(List<Message__c> messages){
    for(Message__c item : messages){
        if(item.Key__c == 'Asset_Register') {
            assetDisplayText = item.Description__c;
            } else if(item.Key__c == 'Invoice_Status') {
                invoiceDisplayText = item.Description__c;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Now you can test this method with whatever input you want.